# External configuration beside app.conf & environment variables for revel go framework

Tags: go, revel

I have read revel [app.conf manual](http://revel.github.io/manual/appconf.html) for custom configuration and environment variables. however I couldn't find way to use additional external configuration along with app.conf.

My goal is to achieve external configuration file in addition to internal app.conf. Let's say creating a product called **example** and example product maintains it's sensible defaults with app.conf (not exposing to end user) instead  product exposes config attributes via example.conf (default location could be /etc/example/example.conf) for product users.

For example: http config field from app.conf

```
http.addr =
http.port = 9000
```

extend it to example.conf

```
http.addr =
http.port = 9000

[database]
host = "localhost"
port = 8080
user = "username"
password = "password"
# etc...
```

Then I read example.conf during an application start use values also apply values on top of app.conf (overriding). Finally revel server starts!

How to achieve this goal with revel go framework?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are working against the design of the app.conf. It is already setup to be sectioned, for example all this is in a single app.conf file

```
[dev]
results.pretty = true
watch = true
http.addr = 192.168.1.2

[test]
results.pretty = true
watch = true
http.addr = 192.168.1.22

[prod]
results.pretty = false
watch = false
http.addr = 192.168.1.100
```

you can launch 3 different scenarios by using three different command line options

```
revel run bitbucket.org/mycorp/my-app dev

revel run bitbucket.org/mycorp/my-app test

revel run bitbucket.org/mycorp/my-app prod
```

I know this is not exactly what your goal is but you can acheive a similar result.

Comment: Thanks, I have understood this capability from documentation.  However as described in question, my goal is not to expose app.conf for end user instead example.conf as product configuration. Any clue/approach to workaround this?

Answer (score 1):

In github.com/revel/revel/revel.go around line 152 you have something like

`Config, err = LoadConfig("app.conf")`.

Maybe you can try and modify that with this

```
if len(os.Getenv("SOME ENV VAR")) > 0 {
    Config, err = LoadConfig("path/to/your/example.conf")
} else {
    Config, err = LoadConfig("app.conf")
}
```

You just need to set env var on your prod server.

That way you will not be using app.conf but your example.conf.

Comment: @jeevatkm tell me what you think about this?

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad to extend framework via some interface which is supported by framework, so when new version comes it will be compatible with that. Else I may have to may maintain my version of revel code and sync it with every release. I have been in that road, not fun efforts

Comment: There is [hook for startup functions](https://github.com/revel/revel/blob/master/server.go#L92) via OnAppStart. do you aware of hooks for config override?